# How to add a xml in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have some complex data which is used for application configuration in xml format. I want to keep this xml string in web.config. Is it possible to add a big xml string in web.config and get it in code everywhere?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a `Settings` file? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: nopes I want to have this xml string in web.config only.not in any other settings file or resource file this is my clients requirement.

Comment: The `Settings` values are stored in web.config. The `Settings.settings` file is used by the designer.

Comment: It's your job to convince your client that **they're doing it wrong**. Using `web.config` as a place to dump other XML simply because it's the same type is a poor excuse. There's already infrastructure for working with data in a `Settings` file in a strongly-typed manner. See jrummell's comment.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to write a configuration section handler, you could just put your XML in a custom configuration section that is mapped to `IgnoreSectionHandler`:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section 
          name="myCustomElement" 
          type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" 
          allowLocation="false" />
    </configSections>
    ...
    <myCustomElement>
        ... complex XML ...
    </myCustomElement>
    ...
</configuration>
```

You can then read it using any XML API, e.g. `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`, `XmlReader` classes.  E.g.:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
XmlElement node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/myCustomElement") as XmlElement;
... etc ...
```

Comment: Probably this is what I looking for.

Comment: Will u plz tell how can I read the "...complex xml..." as a string in my code?

Comment: @Idorado, I added an example of reading the custom element using the XmlDocument class.

Comment: Thank you Joe
This is exactly what i was searching.

Comment: @Gulshan: It's nice to reward this user if his answer solved your issue by [marking the answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: <section> describer must be put in <configuration><configSections> And  <myCustomElement> in <applicationSettings>

Comment: @Joe, Thanks! Nice and clean way to do it.

Comment: @Boogier, No need to put <myCustomElement> in applicationSettings, because, you can define your own Custom Element in the config file this way.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways of achieving what you want (an XML fragment that is globally and statically accessible to your application code):

- The `web.config` is *already* an XML file. You can write a custom configuration section (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)) in order to fetch the data from your custom XML.
- You can encode the XML data (all `<` to `&lt;`, `>` to `&gt`, `&` to `&amp;`, `"` to `&quote;`)
- You can put the XML data in a `<![CDATA[]]>` section
- Don't use `web.config` for this, but a [`Settings` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) as @Yuck commented

That last option is the best one, in terms of ease of development and usage.

Comment: Is it possible to add an array of objects in settings file?

Comment: Not an array, as far as I am aware, but you _can_ add collections (there is a built in StringCollection, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The configuration sections in web.config support long strings, but the string has to be a single line of text  so they can fit into an attribute:

```
 <add name="" value="... some very long text can go in here..." />
```

The string also can't contain quotes or line breaks or other XML markup characters. The data is basically XML and it has to be appropriately encoded.

For example, if you have XML like this:

```
 <root>
   <value>10</value>
 </root>
```

it would have to be stored in a configuration value like this:

```
<add key="Value" value="&lt;root&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;value&gt;10&lt;/value&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/root&gt;" />
```

Which kind of defeats the purpose of a configuration element.

You might be better off storing the configuration value in a separate file on the file system and read it from there into a string or XmlDocument etc.