# Configuring a list in a .net configuration section

Tags: .net, configurationsection

I'm having troubles writing a configuration section for my application.
All I need is to config a list of pairs which I would translate to an object. 
I have seen implementations using ConfigurationElement and ConfigurationElementCollection classes, but it looks horrible, and I actually forced my code and configuration to fit this solution. 
I do NOT want to use  element with key-value attributes becuase it's not what I need.
I want my configuration section to look like this:

```
<MySection>
    <Option>
       <City>aaa</City>
       <Country>bbb</Country>
    </Option>
     <Option>
       <City>ccc</City>
       <Country>ddd</Country>
    </Option>
    <Option>
       <City>eee</City>
       <Country>fff</Country>
    </Option>
</MySection>
```

Another oossible section:

```
<MySection>
    <Option City="aaa" Country="bbb"/>
    <Option City="ccc" Country="ddd"/>
    <Option City="eee" Country="fff"/>
</MySection>
```

Is there any class that might help me parse this without forcing my code to do ugly stuff?

thank you

Comment: what do you exactly mean with configuration section? Is it within some xml file or is it in the app.config/ web.config?

Comment: Ooh, I thought it was clear. It's in the app.config file, and I prefer not to create a seperate xml file and read it as a file...

Comment: Go with custom configuration section and handler

Answer (score 1):

You could go for 2 options:

1. Create a custom configuration section at a similar question on  [How to add a xml in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666873/how-to-add-a-xml-in-web-config) or have a loook at a basic example here: https://web.archive.org/web/20201202223151/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020707-1.aspx
2. If you can store it in a simple list, go for a comma separated string in your appSettings:

> ```
>  <appSettings>
>    <add key="countryName" value="CityA, CityC, CityD" />
>    <add key="countryName2" value="CityB, CityE" />
>  </appsettings>
> ```

And read it like this:

```
string[] citiesPerCountry = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["countryName"].Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
```